# Exercise in a differentiable function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be differentiable on $(a,b)$. Put
$$
f^+(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
f(x)&\text{for }f(x)>0\\
0&\text{for }f(x)\leq0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Show that $(f^+)^2$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, and that its derivative is given by $2f^+(x)f'(x)$ at each $x$ in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Can you share with us your attempts at the solution?

Comment: Since $f$ is differentiable, we have $f$ is continuous. So we consider in  cases. Let $x\in (a,b)$.
Case f(x)>0: we have 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(f^+)^2(x+h)-(f^+)^2(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(f)^2(x+h)-(f)^2(x)}{h}=2f(x)f'(x).
$$
Similarly, for the case $f(x)<0$. But I have a problem in case $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're obviously fine if $f(x)>0$, since $f(x)^{2}$ is differentiable, and you're obviously fine if $f(x)<0$, since $0$ is differentiable. All that remains is to show $f^{+}$ is differentiable when $f(x) = 0$.

Let $\alpha$ be such that $f(\alpha)=0$. WLOG suppose $f(x)>0$ for $x<\alpha$. Then, by definition, the derivative of $f^{+}(x)^{2}$ at $\alpha$ is $$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{f^{+}(\alpha+h)^{2}}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^{-}}\frac{f^{+}(\alpha+h)^{2}}{h}$$
And the task is now to show both of these limits exist and equal $0$. That shouldn't be too hard.